# How can use spark SqlContext object in spark sql registeredFunction?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark SQL. Concat function not available in Spark Sql Query for this we have registered one sql function, with in this function i need access another table. for that we have written spark sql query on SQLContext object.
when i invoke this query i am getting NullpointerException.please can you help on this.

Thanks in advance

//This I My code

```
class SalesHistory_2(sqlContext:SQLContext,sparkContext:SparkContext) extends Serializable   {

import sqlContext._
import sqlContext.createSchemaRDD
try{


sqlContext.registerFunction("MaterialTransformation", Material_Transformation _)

  def Material_Transformation(Material_ID: String): String = 
{     

   var material:String =null;
      var dd = sqlContext.sql("select * from product_master")      

material
}     



  /* Product master*/
    val productRDD = this.sparkContext.textFile("D:\\Realease 8.0\\files\\BHI\\BHI_SOP_PRODUCT_MASTER.txt")        

  val product_schemaString = productRDD.first

  val product_withoutHeaders = dropHeader(productRDD)

  val product_schema = StructType(product_schemaString.split("\\|").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))

  val productdata = product_withoutHeaders.map{_.replace("|", "| ")}.map(x=> x.split("\\|"))
var product_rowRDD = productdata.map(line=>{
 Row.fromSeq(line.map {_.trim() })
})

    val product_srctableRDD = sqlContext.applySchema(product_rowRDD, product_schema)

    product_srctableRDD.registerTempTable("product_master")
    cacheTable("product_master")

    /* Customer master*/


    /* Sales History*/



  val srcRDD = this.sparkContext.textFile("D:\\Realease 8.0\\files\\BHI\\BHI_SOP_TRADE_SALES_HISTORY_DS_4_20150119.txt")

  val schemaString= srcRDD.first

  val withoutHeaders = dropHeader(srcRDD)    

  val schema = StructType(schemaString.split("\\|").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))

  val lines = withoutHeaders.map {_.replace("|", "| ")}.map(x=> x.split("\\|"))
var rowRDD = lines.map(line=>{
 Row.fromSeq(line.map {_.trim() })
})

val srctableRDD = sqlContext.applySchema(rowRDD, schema)

srctableRDD.registerTempTable("SALES_HISTORY")  



 val srcResults = sqlContext.sql("SELECT Delivery_Number,Delivery_Line_Item,MaterialTransformation(Material_ID),Customer_Group_Node,Ops_ID,DC_ID,Mfg_ID,PGI_Date,Delivery_Qty,Customer_Group_Node,Line_Total_COGS,Line_Net_Rev,Material_Description,Sold_To_Partner_Name,Plant_Description,Originating_Doc,Orig_Doc_Line_item,Revenue_Type,Material_Doc_Ref,Mater_Doc_Ref_Item,Req_Delivery_Date FROM  SALES_HISTORY")

 val path: Path = Path ("D:/Realease 8.0/files/output/")
try {
  path.deleteRecursively(continueOnFailure = false) 
} catch {
  case e: IOException => // some file could not be deleted
}

  val successRDDToFile = srcResults.map { x => x.mkString("|")} 
  successRDDToFile.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("D:/Realease 8.0/files/output/")      

  }
  catch {
    case ex: Exception => println(ex) // TODO: handle error
  }   

this.sparkContext.stop()
```

def dropHeader(data: RDD[String]): RDD[String] = {

```
data.mapPartitionsWithIndex((idx, lines) => {
  if (idx == 0) {
    lines.drop(1)
  }
  lines
})
```

}

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi i posted my code on above please look it and help me

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is rather short and probably disappointing - you simply cannot do something like this.

General rule in Spark is you cannot trigger action or transformation from another action and transformation or, to be a little bit more precise, outside the driver Spark Context is no longer accessible / defined.

Answer (score 0):

Calling Spark SQL for each row in the Sales History RDD looks like a very bad idea:

```
val srcResults = sqlContext.sql("SELECT Delivery_Number,Delivery_Line_Item,MaterialTransformation(Material_ID),Customer_Group_Node,Ops_ID,DC_ID,Mfg_ID,PGI_Date,Delivery_Qty,Customer_Group_Node,Line_Total_COGS,Line_Net_Rev,Material_Description,Sold_To_Partner_Name,Plant_Description,Originating_Doc,Orig_Doc_Line_item,Revenue_Type,Material_Doc_Ref,Mater_Doc_Ref_Item,Req_Delivery_Date FROM  SALES_HISTORY")
```

You'd better user a join between your RDDs and forget you custom function:

```
val srcResults = sqlContext.sql("SELECT s.*, p.* FROM  SALES_HISTORY s join product_master p on s.Material_ID=p.ID")
```

Comment: Moreover the code you use to parse your _Pipe Separated_ file looks very complicated. Have a look at [Spark CSV](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv), you can change the column delimiter.

Comment: thanks for suggestions. Before getting data from table i need to do some manipulations on data.like if material id same in both table instead of material id i need to take Material_Transformation from other table like product_loop